# Abstract static property cannot be overwritten?

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

```
abstract class Ghost {

    protected static $var = 'I\'m a ghost';

    final public static function __callStatic($method, $args = array()) {
        echo self::$var;
    }

}


class Person extends Ghost { 
    protected static $var = 'I\'m a person';
}
```

The call of `Person::whatever()` will print: `I'm a ghost`.
Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for something called [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), which requires PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 3):

"self" is used by Current class,
if you want get child static property, use "static" as :

```
final public static function __callStatic($method, $args = array()) {
   echo **static**::$var;
}
```